# How to update page hits when a specific page is visited by the user

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 5.2. How can I increment a hits field in articles table when a specific an article is visited by the user?

This is the code I came up with:

```
Article::where('id', 2)->increment('hits');
```

Where would be the best place to insert this code to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a middleware and then pass your requests through it. so whenever you request artical route it will be passed from that middleware and in middleware you can write logic for your increments.

Comment: @Mahmoud take a look at this little different but can help you [Creating page view increment](http://blog.stidges.com/post/implementing-a-page-view-counter-in-laravel)

Comment: Thanks bro, it helped me, i think this is the only way to do this.

Comment: @Mahmoud Glad it helped

Answer (score 1):

You can place your code in Controller which will display your article.